# Как отключить выделение выбранной картинки?

Tags: html, css

Решил использовать плагин magnific popup для создания модальных окон изображений, но наткнулся на такую проблему: после закрытия изображения вокруг картинки появляется синяя рамка. Как убрать такой эффект?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: outline :none   попробуйте

Comment: @Избытоксусликов Спасибо, получилось! Проблема оказалась в том, что картинка лежит в ссылке, и стиль надо было применять именно ко второй.

Comment: тогда я напишу примите ответ .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В основном для того чтобы избавитсья от таких синих border-ов надо проста в стильях написать

**outline:none**

Свойство `outline` задает 
внешнюю границу вокруг элементов (т.е. за пределами обычной границы). Основная цель данного свойства выделить какой-либо элемент.И поставив `outline none` вы избавляетесь от внешних границ вокруг элемента.

Answer (score 2):

В стилях добавьте outline: none;
Но! Не нужно прописывать это для всех элементов, если вы хотите сделать свой сайт удобным, ведь в таком случае **пользоваться клавиатурой будет попросту невозможно**. Так что используйте его только там, где он необходим.